# Create many header files that just #include many files (act like a hub file)

Tags: c++, include, header-files

[It is a bad idea to stuff a lot of `#include` into 1 file.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138259/is-it-a-good-idea-to-put-all-of-your-includes-in-one-header-file)

My situation is a bit different - I am going to create **more-than-one** hub files contains only **some** `#include`:-

**PhysicCommonHub.h :-**

```
#include "PhysicCompound.h"    //~ 100 lines
#include "PhysicConstraint.h"  //~ 100 lines
#include "PhysicDummy.h"       //~ 100 lines
#include "PhysicUtil.h"        //~ 100 lines
//In real case, I include around 5 files.
```

**GraphicCommonHub.h :-**

```
#include "GraphicMesh.h"           //~ 100 lines
#include "GraphicLightSource.h"    //~ 100 lines
#include "GraphicUtil.h"           //~ 100 lines
```

### **My situation (and incentive) is :-**

- Whenever I want to include a file, there is around 30% that I would also want another file in the same **hub**.
- For example, if `PhysicCompound.h` is included, there is 30% change that I will also have to include `PhysicConstraint.h`, and 30% for `PhysicDummy.h` independently, etc.

Therefore, if I am about to include `PhysicCompound.h`, I will just include `PhysicCommonHub.h`.

**Advantage:-**

- code is cleaner  (shorten)
- convenient, productivity increases (little more than a bit)

**Disadvantage:-**

- maintainability decreases (a bit?)
- compile time increases a bit

### Question

1. Is it worth?   Is it a **bad idea** or a **bad practice**?    Does it just "depend"?
   Is there such **threshold** (in percent) in real business?
   More specifically, is it possible that creating some hubs file is a good decision?
2. What about using the hub-technique just for **forward declaration**?
   More specifically, is there any case that it is a good decision?

**PhysicForwardHub.h :-**

```
class PhysicCompound;
class PhysicConstraint;
class PhysicDummy;
class PhysicUtil;
```

From the close-vote, I will assume that it "depends", i.e. the answers are "yes" for both question. (?)

Comment: Most real-world code is orders of magnitude less readable and less maintainable than anything you propose here. ;)  You can't really prevent a mess from happening regardless of what choice you make early on. _Do whatever is easiest and cleanest to code right now_, and don't worry about it until your project grows to hundreds or thousands of source files (if that ever happens) and your structural choices become an actual issue.

Comment: @paddy  Thank a lot, paddy.  That is a valuable advise.  :)    I feel you implied that the answer depends on the code/project, and I would probably realize which is the best choice at the time my project become big enough.

Comment: No, I implied that you're over-thinking your design, and I suggested that every design is eventually out-grown so you may as well take the hit later if it ever becomes necessary, and get down to the business of writing actual code now.  In regards to your question, I voted to close because I had no idea what you were actually trying to do based on the wording you used, nor what alternative you thought you were preventing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't just describe your approach as "bad practice".   I'd describe it as terrible practice.

Practically, each one of your "hub headers" will have the same effects as described in that question you linked to.

Splitting such headers up (so there is more than one "hub header", like you describe) might mitigate some effects associated with having a single header that include a lot of other headers.    However, that's not a recommendation for your approach.   It is a sign of how bad a single global header is - your approach is simply less awful, rather than offering some "goodness" over alternatives.

Although you have characterised the impacts on maintainability or compilation as "a bit"  (i.e. suggesting they are not significant), the reality is that the impacts are quite significant.    The impacts might not be noticeable in small projects, but they are terrible in larger projects.   Impacts include build times increasing by orders of magnitude, and significant lost productivity (including developers twiddling thumbs waiting for new code to compile, so they can test it).

Using the technique only for forward declarations won't gain much.   There will always be code that needs complete type definitions, rather than just forward declarations.    And using your "hub header" just for forward declarations will, practically, just be a thin edge of the wedge - after all, it is a small step to say "okay, I've done it for forward declarations .... now for the headers with the class definitions ....".

Realistically, although it takes some thought to decide what headers are needed in each compilation unit, that effort will normally be a small proportion of the time spent actually implementing NEW code.   So what you are describing is a false economy - reduces effort thinking about your code, in a way that impacts on all sorts of productivity metrics for the project as a whole.